# How do I get the Ubuntu One client in my native language?

Tags: 11.04, windows, ubuntu-one, language-support, translation

After installing Ubuntu One on 11.04, I decided to install the Windows beta. 
I can't use version 4 because the menus are in English.

Now I can only access my Ubuntu One account using Chrome. I'd like to help, but English is not my native language.

Thank you

Comment: Alain, J'ai essayé de traduire votre question du mieux que je peux. S'il vous plaît commentaire si j'ai fait une erreur, ce site est uniquement en anglais. Si vous pouvez, s'il vous plaît essayer de clarifier votre question. Je ne sais pas ce que vous demandez.

Comment: How's your English? Can you provide a simple translation of your post so the non-French-speakers can understand your post? / Il s'agit d'un forum anglophone. Pourriez-vous traduire en anglais s'il vous plaît?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what affects the display language of installed software, but [this page that lists existing translations](https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/trunk/+pots/ubuntuone-client/fr/+translate) might serve as a reference for using Ubuntu One in English.

Comment: That would be cool if we could leave the original question in French at the end after the translation (so that at least the author would understand what he was asking here). Otherwise, all non-English speakers will be discouraged to use askubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

The Ubuntu One Windows beta is English only as is the Ubuntu One web site.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are no way to translate the Windows application through the standard ways. I think maybe an user who wants to collaborate have to sign [Canonical’s Contributor Agreement](http://www.canonical.com/contributors) and send the translated strings. Maybe when the app goes final stable, we will be able to translate it through Launchpad.